# Find Child Object in Parent Object using Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, sequelize.js

I have three tables in MySQL database:- categoryTypes, categories and categoryTemplates.
The parent table is categoryTypes. In categoryTypes, there are the following fields and id of categoryTypes is stored as a foreign key in categories table. The dummy data as following:-

```
"id": 1,
"name": "testing1",
"img": "assets/images/img-1584341288506.png",
"status": "ACTIVE",
```

In categories table, there are the following fields and there is a field named as categoryTypeRef where primary key of categoryTypes is stored as foreign key. The dummy data:-

```
"id": 1,
"name": "testing1236",
"img": "assets/images/img-1584341317490.png",
"status": "ACTIVE",
"categoryTypeRef": 1,
```

In categoryTemplates table, category id is stored as foreign key in category templates tableand the dummy data is:-

```
"id": 2,
"status": "ACTIVE",
"brandName": "Havells",
"purchasingCost": 10000,
"specifications": "{\n  \"TextBox\": [\n    {\n      \"labelText\": \"Text Box 1\",\n      \"valueText\": \"1234577800\",\n      \"requireTextBox\": false\n    },\n    {\n      \"labelText\": \"Text Box 2\",\n      \"valueText\": \"15264848\",\n      \"requireTextBox\": false\n    }\n  ],\n  \"TextArea\": [\n    {\n      \"labelTextArea\": \"bdbhd\",\n      \"valueTextArea\": \"hdhdhd\",\n      \"requireTextArea\": false\n    }\n  ]\n}",
"serialNo": null,
"warrantyMonths": 18,
"categoryRef": 1,
```

I want to retrieve category type as different object while getting category templates object.
 **My expected solution is:-**

```
"categoryTemplate": {
            "id": 2,
            "status": "ACTIVE",
            "brandName": "Havells",
            "purchasingCost": 10000,
            "specifications": "{\n  \"TextBox\": [\n    {\n      \"labelText\": \"Text Box 1\",\n      \"valueText\": \"1234577800\",\n      \"requireTextBox\": false\n    },\n    {\n      \"labelText\": \"Text Box 2\",\n      \"valueText\": \"15264848\",\n      \"requireTextBox\": false\n    }\n  ],\n  \"TextArea\": [\n    {\n      \"labelTextArea\": \"bdbhd\",\n      \"valueTextArea\": \"hdhdhd\",\n      \"requireTextArea\": false\n    }\n  ]\n}",
            "serialNo": null,
            "warrantyMonths": 18,
            "categoryRef": 1,
            "category": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "testing1236",
                "img": "assets/images/img-1584341317490.png",
                "status": "ACTIVE",
                "categoryTypeRef": 1,
            },
           "categoryType": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "testing1",
                    "img": "assets/images/img-1584341288506.png",
                    "status": "ACTIVE",
                }
        }
```

**I applied following sequelize query:-**

```
 const categoryTemplate = await CategoryTemplate.findAll({
            where: {
              id: body.categoryTemplateRef
            },
            include: [
              {
                model: Category,
                include: [CategoryType]
              }
            ]
          });
```

**My actual result is:-**

```
"categoryTemplate": {
            "id": 2,
            "status": "ACTIVE",
            "brandName": "Havells",
            "purchasingCost": 10000,
            "specifications": "{\n  \"TextBox\": [\n    {\n      \"labelText\": \"Text Box 1\",\n      \"valueText\": \"1234577800\",\n      \"requireTextBox\": false\n    },\n    {\n      \"labelText\": \"Text Box 2\",\n      \"valueText\": \"15264848\",\n      \"requireTextBox\": false\n    }\n  ],\n  \"TextArea\": [\n    {\n      \"labelTextArea\": \"bdbhd\",\n      \"valueTextArea\": \"hdhdhd\",\n      \"requireTextArea\": false\n    }\n  ]\n}",
            "serialNo": null,
            "warrantyMonths": 18,
            "categoryRef": 1,
            "category": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "testing1236",
                "img": "assets/images/img-1584341317490.png",
                "status": "ACTIVE",
                "categoryTypeRef": 1,
                "categoryType": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "testing1",
                    "img": "assets/images/img-1584341288506.png",
                    "status": "ACTIVE",
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance if anyone help with this.

Answer (score 0):

categoryTemplate.categoryType = categoryTemplate.category.categoryType

that mean create a new field on your object *categoryTemplate* named *categoryType* and store on it the object *categoryTemplate.category.categoryType*

Comment: Sorry but I am not getting you.
 can you please describe it?